# "ErrorGeneratingOutput" when compiling Database.tt

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a project which includes Entity Framework.

When an error occured, the script will fail with the output "ErrorGeneratingOutput". This will cause the whole project to NOT compile, because the generated file is a `.cs` file, with (at that point of time) invalid content.

So that a vicious dependency circle, which can only be broken if I manually remove the error message from the generated file, and then trigger the build.

How to solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm also dealing with ErrorGeneratingOutput messaging from a T4 file and looking for answers.